# Getting the height of the xaxisGrob

Tags: r

The `grid`-package has a special tool for generating axis. It writes the axis outside the current viewport and the height using `grobHeight` is therefore considered to be 0mm. Unfortunately I need to make space for the axis and I want to know the exact height of the object. Below is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
library(grid)
plotColorBar <- function () {
  grid.newpage()
  xg <- xaxisGrob(at=c(0,.25,.5,.75, 1),
                  label= sprintf("%d %%", c(0,.25,.5,.75, 1)*100),
                  main=FALSE)

  bar_layout <- grid.layout(nrow=3, ncol=3,
                            heights = unit.c(unit(.80, "npc"),
                                             grobHeight(xg),
                                             unit(.2, "npc") - grobHeight(xg)),
                            widths = unit.c(unit(.25, "npc"),
                                            unit(1, "npc") - 
                                              unit(.5, "npc"),
                                            unit(.25, "npc")))

  pushViewport(viewport(layout=bar_layout, name="Bar_layout"))

  pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=3, 
                        layout.pos.col=2, 
                        name="Color_bar"))

  grid.draw(xg)
  bar_clrs <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"), space="Lab")(101)
  grid.raster(t(as.raster(bar_clrs)), width=1, height=1, interpolate=FALSE)

  popViewport()

  pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=1, 
                        layout.pos.col=1:3, 
                        name="Main_exc_bar"))

  grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="black", fill="#00000022"))
  grid.text("Coool")
  popViewport()
}

png(filename="axisWihtoutHeight.png", width=250, height=250, res=96)
plotColorBar()
dev.off()
```

Gives the following image:

[image: No height]

Notice that the grey area covers the axis text. When I try `convertY(grobHeight(xg), "mm")` it returns 0mm.

Now applying the @baptiste recommended fix improves the image slightly:

```
heightDetails.xaxis = function(x) do.call(sum, lapply(x$children, grobHeight))
png(filename="axisWihtHeight.png", width=250, height=250, res=96)
plotColorBar()
dev.off()
```

[image: Better but still not good]

As you can see the text for some reason is twice the height. Adjusting this manually through the following option although this does feel a little clumsy:

```
heightDetails.xaxis = function(x) {
  grobHeight(x$children$ticks) + 
    grobHeight(x$children$labels) +
    grobHeight(x$children$labels)
}
png(filename="axisWihtDoubleHeight.png", width=250, height=250, res=96)
plotColorBar()
dev.off()
```

[image: Double height seems to fix the issue]

## Final solution

As suggested it seems that unit(1.5*cex, "line") does the job nicely:

```
heightDetails.xaxis = function(x) {
  cex <- 1
  if (!is.null(x$children$labels$gp$cex))
    cex <- x$children$labels$gp$cex

  grobHeight(x$children$ticks) + 
    unit(1.5*cex, "line")
}
```

Comment: rather than doubling the label height, you should apparently add `unit(1.5, "line")`... the reason is somewhat mysterious to me, and hidden in `grid:::make.xaxis.labels` (a recent change from `drawDetails` to `makeContext` as [described here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/customGridRedesign.pdf). To be honest, I would design my own axis grob, I never really found the grid version very appealing.

Comment: and by-the-way, have a look at rasterGrob for the colorbar, or at least vectorise gpar() and rectGrob (no need for a loop)

Comment: @baptiste Excellent, I've added the final code - it seems to work nicely even with adjusted cex-parameters and the rasterGrob was awesome. I can't understand why the height function isn't included by default in the grid-package, I've guessed the height up until now with mixed outcomes - this will certainly improve my plot-functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll want to define a heightDetails method for the gTree, something along those lines

```
heightDetails.xaxis = function(x) do.call(sum, lapply(x$children, grobHeight))
```

Comment: Thank you. I've explored the options in my updated question. I've always found the height of the textGrob a little confusing - it seems that the height is defined as upper case letters, not including yjpq that adds another .5 to the height and in this case I had to double the height. I would also like to understand the gTree object better - it contains children objects but the drawing of it is a complete mystery to me... If you know some good reference that would help me understand the heights better it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Excellent! Once I realized that there was no `heightDetails` method for `gTree` objects, I searched SO for `baptiste` and `heightDetails`; it brought me straight to a solution, just as I'd expected it would ;).

Comment: I believe [things might have changed with makeContext and makeContent](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/murrell.pdf), but I haven't looked into it